# Website not connected to content catalog (hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I followed those steps:

https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294094418

Changing `mystoreinitialdata/coredata` impexes

After those steps, I can see my `content, product and classification` on `catalog/catalogs` on backoffice.

But when I go to `wcms/websites`, i see 5 items. `apparelde, uk, electronics, powertools and my newly created mystore.`

mystore does not have `name , active=true and content catalogs` is empty.

I want to add my catalog to website by programmatically.

I think it is about coredata , not sampledata.

when I search

```
mystore site
```

it can be found only here

```
# Language
$lang=en

# Create CMS Site
UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];name[lang=$lang];locale[lang=$lang]
;mystore;"Mystore Site";en_GB

import/coredata/stores/mystore/site_en.impex
```

But powertools has two more `powertools site`

```
# CMS Navigation Nodes
UPDATE CMSNavigationNode;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];title[lang=$lang]
;;AcceleratorNavNode;"Accelerator"
;;FollowUsNavNode;"Follow Us"
;;HybrisNavNode;"Hybris"
;;MyAccountNavNode;"My Account"
;;PowertoolsNavNode;"Powertools Site"
;;SiteRootNode;"SiteRoot"

##-- level 2. children of SiteRoot --##
INSERT_UPDATE CMSNavigationNode;uid[unique=true];$contentCV[unique=true];name;parent(uid, $contentCV);links(&componentRef);&nodeRef
;PowertoolsNavNode;;Powertools Site;SiteRootNode;;PowertoolsNavNode
```

which are in cms-content and cms-content en impexes.

Should I add them or another way ?

Because apparel does only have one too , same folder as mystore

```
# Language
$lang=en

# Create CMS Site
UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];name[lang=$lang];locale[lang=$lang]
 ;apparel-de;"Apparel Site DE";en_GB
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the catalogs per impex files. The correct impex files for this is under:

**\src\hybris\bin\custom\xx\xxinitialdata\resources\xxinitialdata\import\coredata\stores\xxSite\site.impex**

An than with the following impex line you set the catalog to the site:

```
# CMS Site
INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];theme(code);channel(code);stores(uid);contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id);defaultLanguage(isoCode);siteMapConfig(&siteMapConfigId);urlPatterns;active;previewURL;startingPage(uid,$contentCV);urlEncodingAttributes;defaultPromotionGroup(Identifier)[default=$promoGrp];salesOrg(code)[default=$siteUid];
;$siteUid;blue;B2C;$storeUid;$contentCatalog;$productCatalog;$defaultLanguage;$storeUidSiteMapConfig;$cmsSiteUrlPattern;true;$storefrontContextRoot/?site=$siteUid;homepage;storefront,language;
```

It is exactly this expession:

```
INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id)
;$siteUid;$contentCatalog;$productCatalog
```